# Find $x$ such that $5^{x} ≡ 3 \bmod 2017$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Find $x$ such that $5^{x} ≡ 3 \bmod 2017$.

Any ideas how to solve this? I was thinking this while doing a math problem, my idea was to use primitive roots modulo $2017$, and it led to this problem. Using a computer, I find out $x=1030$, but I don't know how to prove or find $x$ without using a computer. Thank you so much for any comments.

Comment: This is in general not easy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm

Comment: Out of curiosity: what sort of "math problem" requires you to solve this congruence? Could it be that that "math problem" has a simpler solution that does not require you to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You look for patterns LHS is 0 mod 5 so,3+2017(y) must be as well that makes 3+2(y) in reduced form. y must be 1 mod 5.

Mod 4, we have $1^x-3\equiv 2\pmod 4\equiv y \pmod 4$

Using CRT we get y being 6 modulo 20.  This means we are really solving $5^x\equiv 12105 \pmod {40340}$ we could try modulo 9 getting $5^x\equiv 2z\pmod 9$

This makes a short list:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline x\bmod 6& z\bmod 9\\\hline 1 & 7\\\hline 2 & 8\\\hline 3 & 4 \\\hline 4 & 2 \\\hline 5 & 1 \\\hline 0 & 5\\\hline\end{array}$$

Now to brute force ...

Or use y being 16 mod 25 and 6 mod 20 to combine to 66 mod 100 then redo the mod 6 and mod 9 table... Or use Hensel's lifting lemma.